# What's wrong with my recursive delete?

Tags: powershell, delete-file

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse | ? {$_.Extension -eq ".obj" } | %{del $_}
                                                           ~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Temp\compilerLimits\template.obj:String)    [Remove-Item], ItemNotFoundException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.RemoveItemCommand
```

Trying to recursively delete all .obj files;
instead I get this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
Get-ChildItem -recurse *.obj | Remove-Item
```

In the case of `| %{del $_}`, `$_` is a System.IO.FileInfo object and when PowerShell uses this for the LiteralPath parameter, it sees that the LiteralPath parameter takes a string.  The conversion of FileInfo to a string seems to use the FileInfo.ToString() method which in some cases (like for subdirs) doesn't include the full path - just the filename.  That will cause the error your are seeing.  When you pipe in the FileInfo object, pipeline argument binding rules are used.  The LiteralPath parameter has an alias called PSPath.  This property is added to each FileInfo object by PowerShell's type system. You can see this with `Get-ChildItem *.obj | Get-Member`.  And since the LiteralPath parameter has ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName set to true, PowerShell will get the argument value from the object's PSPath property.

You can read more about this in [Item 8 of my Effective PowerShell ebook](http://1drv.ms/1fWltyd).

Comment: Thank you. Does powershell use .net api under the hood for everything or something?

Comment: It uses .NET API extensively. There is some use of DCOM and likely some pinvokes to Win32.

Comment: Nice book that might actually be better than the other powershell books I'm reading. Just wanted to mention the part about `foreach` and `$null` under `Working with Empty Sets` should be updated to at least note v3 has fixed that behavior.

Comment: @JesseGood Thanks.  It's been on my "todo" list for a while now to do an update for V3 and V4.